# Output is nan while it shouldn't be

Tags: c++, nan

I need to calculate the following:

> S= 1- x^2 / 2! + x^4 / 4! - x^6 / 6! + ... + (-1)^n * x^2n / (2n)!
>
> Where n is between 1 and 100, and x is a double.

I have the following code:

```cpp
unsigned int factorial (unsigned int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
}

double exFive(int n, double x)
{
    double s = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        int j = 2 * i; 
        s = s + pow(-1, i) * pow(x, 2*i) / factorial(j); //problem is here I guess
    }

    return s;
}

void fiveIO()
{
    int n = 1;
    double x;
   
    cout << "Input n: ";
    cin >> n;
    while ((n < 1) || (n > 100))
    {
        cout << "Wrong number, input again: ";
        cin >> n;
    } 

    cout << "Input: ";
    cin >> x;

    cout << "Result is " << fixed << setprecision(2) << exFive(n, x);
}
```

It works however the result is nan where n is above ~15.. but I don't know why.
I would presume it’s the FiveX function.

So, for instance, n = 3, x = 5 outputs -7.16 (which is correct), but n = 50, x = 5 outputs "nan".. is it because the output is too large of a number? But then how am I supposed to do it?

Comment: Typical 32-bit `int` can only hold result of `factorial(12)`, any bigger `n` will result in integer overflow. `NaN` is a result of division of a `float` by `0`.

Comment: And a 64 bit number only handles ~`20!`.

Comment: 200! has 375 digits: if you want to brute force that problem you are going to need some extended precision library eg `GMP`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I thought that `NAN` was generated by `0.0/0.0` or `inf-inf`

Comment: @MatG Uh, yeah, you're right. Division by zero should produce `inf`,`0.0 / 0.0`, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid `int` overflow (*undefined behavior* (UB)) in `factorial(j)` [Typical 32-bit int can only hold result of factorial(12)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69546067/output-is-nan-while-it-shouldnt-be#comment122925635_69546067).

Improve loop computation by calculating the `term` based on its prior value.

```
//for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
//    int j = 2 * i; 
//    s = s + pow(-1, i) * pow(x, 2*i) / factorial(j); //problem is here I guess
//}

// Something like
double xx = x*x;
double term = 1.0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    int j = 2 * i; 
    term *= -xx / ((j-1)*j);
    s += term;
}
```

---

A more advanced approach would calculate the sum in reverse to minimize computation errors, yet a lot depends on the allowable range of `x`, something not constrained by OP.

Comment: I tried it and it keeps outputting 0.28 for n = 50,51,52,53 etc, and x = 5. If I change the x to 6 for instance, the output changes to 0.96 but still repeats itself when n is changed. Unless I interpreted it wrong.

Comment: @danee OK, what is expected with "outputting 0.28 for n = 50,51,52,53 etc, and x = 5.".  Is that output incorrect?  For modest `x`, the series converges so I would not expect more terms to change the result.  (Be sure to use the latest version of this answer)

Comment: Touché, I just assumed it's not right. I honestly don't even know how to check it unless I calculate it on paper which would take some time.. I just don't see why it would repeat itself since one round it subtracts and one round it ads to the sum (because of the "(-1)^n"). So I would guess it should fluctuate.

Comment: @danee Yes, but the fluctuation `term` may be so small compared to `sum` that `sum += term` does not change value.  Tip try `setprecision(20)` for more insight.

Comment: @danee Does it work for "n = 3, x = 5 outputs -7.16 (which is correct),"?

Comment: It works for n = 3, x = 5.. Also tried setprecision(20) but it's still the same at higher numbers.

Comment: @danee "... the same at higher numbers." --> which is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For the formula:

> S= 1- x^2 / 2! + x^4 / 4! - x^6 / 6! + ... + (-1)^n * x^2n / (2n)!

I submit this implementation scales slightly better since it avoids multiplying everything at once.

```
double exFive(int n, double x)
{
    double s = 1;

    bool subtract = true;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        double inner = 1;
        int n2 = i * 2;
        for (int j = 1; j <= n2; j++)
        {
            inner *= (x / j);
        }

        if (subtract)
        {
            s = s - inner;
        }
        else
        {
            subtract = s + inner;
        }
        subtract = !subtract;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Sample Run:

```
Input n: 100
Input: 94
Result is -4417.00
```

The implementation above, when it needs to compute say `(x^n)/(n!)`.  Instead of computing

```
T  = (x*x*x*x....*x*x*x) / (1*2*3*4*5*6*....*(N-1)*N)`
```

In the above expression, both the numerator and denominator will overflow when attempting to compute either using `pow` of `factorial` functions.  So instead it will compute it as:

```
T = (x/1) * (x/2) * (x/3) * (x/4) * (x/5) * (x/6)
```

This avoids using factorial and pow functions. And since each iteration of the outer loop is alternating subtraction or addition operations, the chance of overflow remains smaller.

Comment: Yes, but for n = 3, x = 5 it outputs -11.5, although it should be -7.16 (the exercise gives that i/o as an example)